# Long precise numbers in C?

Tags: c, types

I am making a program that prints the first 100 Lucas numbers(they are like Fibonacci), but the last few numbers don't fit in unsigned long long int. I tried using long double, but it isn't precise and I get some differences with what I am supposed to get.

This is a homework task and my teacher specifically specified we do not need to use any other library than stdio.h.

I tried making a method that adds strings as numbers, but it is way beyond out experience and I sincerely doubt that is what we have to do.

With imprecisions it looks something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long double firstNumber = 2;
    long double secondNumber = 1;
    long double thirdNumber;

    int i;
    for (i = 2; i <= 100; i += 1)
    {
        thirdNumber = secondNumber + firstNumber;
        firstNumber = secondNumber;
        secondNumber = thirdNumber;
        printf("%Lf, ", thirdNumber);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know about arrays?  You could, for example, store a single "number" as an array of digits where each element contains 0 to 9.  Since the operations are only addition, it should be pretty easy to implement array addition (don't forget to normalize after addition).

Comment: @WhozCraig a 64-bit unsigned int's max is `18446744073709551615`, but L100 is `792070839848372253127` according to WolframAlpha. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=what+is+the+100th+Lucas+number%3F

Comment: Read about [bignums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) and see http://gmplib.org/

Comment: Best way would be using array and doing old school mathematics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like all you need is addition. I see three ways you can go about this.

- If you weren't forbidden from using libraries then you'd use one of the many bigint libraries commonly available.
- Implement a string-based adder. You'd basically implement the addition method you learned in 3rd grade.
- As a hack, if your largest number fits in roughly two `unsigned long long ints` then you can split your number up into Most Significant Digits and Least Significant Digits. I'd go this route.

Comment: I tried using a library, but so far I have only programmed on .Net and have no experience with this. It seems simple... I downloaded bign.lib or something like that and included it, but the compiler didn't recognise big_n as a new type for some reason...

Comment: I think your teacher doesn't want you to use a library (grading would be a huge pain). But if you insist, look up a newbie guide on how to use libraries on your platform. Newer languages have automated a lot of things you need to do to use a library, C and C++ still make you do it manually. It sounds like you need to include another header, but if you get stuck with the library then ask a separate question about that problem.

Comment: Storing the numbers as string is very inefficient

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc doesn't matter. L_100 is still only 21 digits, so the program doesn't need more than about 70 bytes of storage for the *least* efficient method, and it only has to compute 100 additions.

Answer (score 1):

I used below to store really large numbers in an array. Pasting the code below with some comments. Hope it helps.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t;
    int a[200]; //array will have the capacity to store 200 digits.
    int n,i,j,temp,m,x;

    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
       scanf("%d",&n);
       a[0]=1;  //initializes array with only 1 digit, the digit 1.
       m=1;    // initializes digit counter

       temp = 0; //Initializes carry variable to 0.
       for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
       {
            for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
               x = a[j]*i+temp; //x contains the digit by digit product
               a[j]=x%10; //Contains the digit to store in position j
               temp = x/10; //Contains the carry value that will be stored on later indexes
            }
             while(temp>0) //while loop that will store the carry value on array.
             { 
               a[m]=temp%10;
               temp = temp/10;
               m++; // increments digit counter
             }
      }
              for(i=m-1;i>=0;i--) //printing answer
              printf("%d",a[i]);
              printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```